# Magento Pager is not showing in product list.phtml

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.8, magento-enterprise

In magento I override product list.phtml, its working fine but pager is not showing. I already included code in xml as well as in list.phtml for pager but not showing. Please help.

Thanks in advance

below code for list.phtml

```
$this->getToolbarHtml()
```

And for xml code

```
     <catalog_category_default translate="label">
                <reference name="head">
                    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/product.js</script></action>
                    <action method="addJs"><script>varien/configurable.js</script></action>
                    <action method="addItem"><type>js_css</type><name>calendar/calendar-win2k-1.css</name><params/><!--<if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                    <action method="addItem"><type>js</type><name>calendar/calendar-setup.js</name><!--<params/><if/><condition>can_load_calendar_js</condition>--></action>
                    <action method="addItem"><type>skin_js</type><name>js/bundle.js</name></action>
                </reference>
         <reference name="content">

        <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="quickview/catalog/product/list.phtml">
        <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
         <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                        </block>
                    </block> 


                </reference>
</catalog_category_default>
```

Answer (score 2):

add  this action and see..

```
 <block type="catalog/product_list" name="product_list" template="quickview/catalog/product/list.phtml">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml">
             <block type="page/html_pager" name="product_list_toolbar_pager"/>
                            </block>
           <action method="setToolbarBlockName"><name>product_list_toolbar</name></action>
                        </block>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, i already trying with limit but no success.